# Why I can't connect Mongodb server in Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I want to develop ToDoApp with React and MongoDb. I created database in MongoDb Atlas and entegrated to my react. In local, everything is working but in heroku, I got error.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();

let Todo = require('./todo.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<MyUsername>:<MyPassword>@asnus-sql-5enaw.mongodb.net/todolist', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

...
...
...
```

```
...
...
...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy":"http://localhost:4000"
}
```

This is my app in heroku, you can see 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error in console:
https://asnus-todolist.herokuapp.com

And if you want you can see my code in github:
https://github.com/sametsunman/ToDoList

Comment: in MongoDb Atlas  panel, did you allowed all IPs in whitelist? Maybe it is not accepting connections from heroku app server.

Comment: Yes, i added 0.0.0.0/0 ip but its not worked

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. I was able to get some sort of connection by getting the host with `const loc = window.location; const origin = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.hostname;` and then using the host location in the get strings i.e.: `axios.get(\`${origin}:4000/crowdedroom/\`)`. Although it stops the Connection Refused error, it doesn't return any response (for me at least), and the connection just hangs.